# Preserve Lightning app Querystrings in Salesforce Mobile App

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-apps, mobile, querystrings

I have a Lightning app page which relies on querystrings to show parts of the page. This looks something like this

> **...lightning.force.com/lightning/n/MyApp?c__view=landing**

This works perfectly using a desktop browser.

However, when accessing the same page in SF Mobile (i.e. clicking the same hyperlink from an email which launches via SF app), it seems to be stripping out the querystrings.

Is there a way I can keep querystrings when using SF Mobile?

Please advise.